# Exporting CAD model to Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, cad

This is my first post here so I would like to welcome all of you. 
I need some help with a CAD/Matlab problem. I want to export a CAD model to Matlab and be able to process this model by applying orthogonal projection into X,Y axis with depth values information - Z-buffer. I have already read about STL files and found some tools to import such files to Matlab but STL gives only information about surfaces, which is not sufficient enough to solve my problem. My question is, in which format should I export model from CAD to be able to process it in Matlab and what kind of tool/code should I use?
Could you please give me some hints or simple codes in matlab? Thank you in advice.

Regards,
Wito

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3642-cad2matdemo-m ? I know it's also "only" STL with a surface, but looks as if you could find out a depth and projectation

Comment: I've already seen this program but I don't know how to make use of the vertexes and faces to apply orthogonal projection. Is it possible at all?

Comment: Am I mistaken or does it help you to display the levels of height like this: http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/contour.html of the surface?